# How to split string from XML content and get the required value

Tags: sql-server, openxml

Hello all I am converting an xml content and inserting it to a table variable as follows

````
DECLARE @iDoc int

SET @XMLData = '<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <DataId>2324205.3933251.7336404</DataId>
    <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
    <Notes />
    <Marks>85.5</Marks>
   </Table>
   </NewDataSet>' 

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XMLData 

SELECT DataId FROM OPENXML(@idoc, 'NewDataSet/Table', 1)
WITH   (DataId NVARCHAR(250) 'DataId')```

I would like to split the dot value and retrieve the the first value, can some one help me how to can I do that with in XML

IsVisible is a bit filed, Marks is deicmal like that I will have
````

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: my local 2014 version, the actual is on azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is better to use XQuery language, based on the w3c standards, while dealing with the XML data type.
Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
It is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Notes NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Notes) VALUES
(N'<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <DataId>2324205.3933251.7336404</DataId>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , TRY_CAST(Notes AS XML).value('(/NewDataSet/Table/DataId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS x
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * 
    , LEFT(x, CHARINDEX('.', x) - 1) AS [After]
    , PARSENAME(x, 3) AS [After2]
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
+-------------------------+---------+
|         Before          |  After  |
+-------------------------+---------+
| 2324205.3933251.7336404 | 2324205 |
+-------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: OK if I have another columns along with this will it work?

Comment: @Developer, While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @Developer, Please edit your question, and provide ##1-4, and I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry my bad I thought it can be using openxml

Comment: @Developer, I don't see any DB table DDL in your question. #1 is missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233761/discussion-between-developer-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).